# equivalent of simplexml_load_file in symfony 2

Tags: symfony, request

How do I achieve the same thing as below, standard PHP, but using symfony 2

```
 $xml = simplexml_load_file($_FILES['updates']['tmp_name']);
```

Comment: Use it so! Maybe put a `\` in front, like `\simplexml_load_file()` because of the namespaces.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use standard PHP code in Symfony2 Projects, but you should try to use the framework modules. Otherwise you don't need a framework.

You can access requests in a controller by

```
$this -> getRequest()
```

The request consists of request parameters (sent via POST) and query parameters (sent by GET). So first thing you can try is to look for getRequest() -> request or getRequest() -> query. I don't think you will find the tmp file there, but you can try.

Next idea:
Symfony supports forms and the form type file.
Imagine you have a container class such as:

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\File\UploadedFile;

// ...
class Document
{
    /**
     * @Assert\File(maxSize="6000000")
     */
    private $file;

    /**
     * Sets file.
     *
     * @param UploadedFile $file
     */


    public function setFile(UploadedFile $file = null)
    {
        $this->file = $file;
    }

    /**
     * Get file.
     *
     * @return UploadedFile
     */
    public function getFile()
    {
        return $this->file;
    }
```

}

Build a form for this container class and handle the request:

```
/**
 * @Template()
 */
public function uploadAction(Request $request)
{
    $document = new Document();
    $form = $this->createFormBuilder($document)
        ->add('name')
        ->add('file')
        ->getForm();

    $form->handleRequest($request);

    if ($form->isValid()) {
        // here you can access the file via $document -> getFile()
        // entity manager must only be used if the container class is managed
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();

        $em->persist($document);
        $em->flush();

        return $this->redirect($this->generateUrl(...));
    }

    return array('form' => $form->createView());
}
```

After creating the object, you can access the file.